# How to submit multi HTML form without redirection

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I was using this form

```
<form action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
        <p class="act-large act-center">Name:&nbsp;<input id="uploaderName" name="uploaderName" required="required" type="text" /></p>

        <p class="act-large act-center">Choose file to send: <input id="fileToUpload" name="fileToUpload" type="file" /> <input name="submit" style="vertical-align:middle" type="submit" value="Send" /></p>
        </form>
```

and import Js

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#submit").click(function(){
    var upload = $("#fileToUpload").val();
    $.post("upload.php", {text: upload});
    $("#fileToUpload").attr("value", "");
    $("#uploaderName").attr("value", "");
    return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

but when i was submit the form, it keeps redirect to upload.php
anybody know this problem? please help me, it for my assignment.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't declare the `id="submit"` inside the input, try this:

```
<form action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
        <p class="act-large act-center">Name:&nbsp;<input id="uploaderName" name="uploaderName" required="required" type="text" /></p>

        <p class="act-large act-center">Choose file to send: <input id="fileToUpload" name="fileToUpload" type="file" /> <input name="submit" style="vertical-align:middle" type="submit" value="Send" id="submit"/></p>
        </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use $.ajax method for this

```
        jQuery.ajax({
        url: "submit.php",
        data: dataString,
        type: "POST",
        success: function(data){
            $("#myForm").html(data);
        },
        error: function (){}
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
<form action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
<p class="act-large act-center">Name:&nbsp;<input id="uploaderName" name="uploaderName" required="required" type="text" /></p>`
<p class="act-large act-center">Choose file to send: <input id="fileToUpload" name="fileToUpload" type="file" /> <input name="submit" style="vertical-align:middle" type="submit" value="Send" id="submit"/></p>
</form>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#submit").click(function(){    
   var upload = $("#fileToUpload").val();
   $.post("upload.php", {text: upload});
   $("#fileToUpload").attr("value", "");
   $("#uploaderName").attr("value", "");
   return false;
  });
 });
</script>`
```